# How to use Jquery Datepicker in Django admin-interface?

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to customize my admin site by adding a Jquery UI--Jquery Datepicker in the right sidebar or the calendar appears when I click the input box .

The calendar is used to pick out a day that filters the data I need. Any help or idea would be appreciated.

admin.py

```
class DecadeBornListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Years')
    parameter_name = 'decade'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('2015', _('2015')),
        ('2014', _('2014')),
            ('2013', _('2013')),
        )


    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == '2015':
                    return queryset.filter(pub_date__gte=date(2015, 1, 1),pub_date__lte=date(2015, 12, 31))
        if self.value() == '2013':
                    return queryset.filter(pub_date__gte=date(2013, 1, 1),pub_date__lte=date(2013, 12, 31))
        if self.value() == '2014':
                    return queryset.filter(pub_date__gte=date(2014, 1, 1),pub_date__lte=date(2014, 12, 31))


class WaterMapAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('pub_date','status','position','na','mei')
    list_filter=('pub_date',DecadeBornListFilter)

    search_fields = ['status']


admin.site.register(WaterMap,WaterMapAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class WaterMap(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('发布日期')
    status=models.CharField('状态',max_length=10)
    position=models.IntegerField('位置')
    na=models.FloatField('纳',default=0.00)
    mei=models.FloatField('镁',default=0.00)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pub_date)[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you implement your form at your template with Django, it"s something like this :

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
  <div>
   {{field}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

To use Datepicker you need to put an id into your inputs like this:

```
<input id="datepicker" ...>
```

So you can write this in your form.py:

```
status= forms.CharField('状态', max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'id for datepicker'}))
```

Comment: Thanks,I can get a Jquery datepicker UI now. And does it right to override the filter.html under the template dictionary if I want to let the UI appear in the right sidebar?